# Sudoku algorithm not backtracking properly

Tags: java

I'm making a Sudoku solver which tries every possible value in a square and backtracks if it doesn't lead to a solution. I believe I have a nearly-working algorithm, but it only has worked so far on rows 0, 2, and 3 of a 16-cell puzzle.

```
public boolean fillBoard(int[][] board, int row, int col){
    int index = 1;              //Next value to try when an empty is found
    boolean solved = false;

    for(int i = row; i < width; i++){       //For each row
        for(int j = col; j < height; j++){  //For each column
            if(board[i][j]==0){             //0 represents empty
                while(!solved){
                    board[i][j] = index;
                    if(checker.checkRow(board[i]) 
                            && checker.checkColumn(columnToArray(board, j))
                            //&& checker.checkBox(<input>)
                            ){
                            solved = fillBoard(board, i, 0);
                    }else{
                        if(index < width){
                            index++;
                        }else{
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    puzzle = copyPuzzle(board);
    return true;
}
```

Right now it doesn't check for the third Sudoku rule, it only checks for columns and rows. However, it should still return a puzzle that follows the row and column rules, right? And once the checkBox method is written, it should just be able to solve the puzzle. Where did I mess up here?

EDIT with a few examples:

For an input of

```
        {1, 2, 0, 0},
        {0, 4, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 3, 2}
```

The program returns

`1 2 4 3 
 4 4 4 4 
 2 3 1 4 
 4 1 3 2`

For an input of

```
        {1, 0},
        {2, 0}
```

It solves it correctly.

For an input of

```
        { 1, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0 },
        { 4, 0, 6, 0, 0, 3 },
        { 2, 0, 1, 0, 6, 0 },
        { 5, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0 },
        { 3, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0 },
        { 6, 0, 5, 0, 0, 2 }
```

It returns the puzzle unsolved

EDIT: `checkRow` for those who have asked

```
public boolean checkRow(int[]row){
    HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < row.length;i++){
        if(!set.add(row[i]) && row[i]>0){//Duplicate?
            return false;
                    }
                }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please provide specific example(s) of it not working.

Comment: @ScottHunter I added a few examples

Comment: Are `checkRow` and `checkColumn` just verifying that current row/column don't contain `0`? The degenerate case for your recursion seems poorly defined, which would explain the algorithm returning an unsolved puzzle in the last instance. I'm thinking your `return true` needs to be `return solved`, and the value of `solved` needs to be updated for your base case.

Comment: @nbrooks `checkRow` and `checkColumn` add the values of the row or column to a set, unless the value is 0, and if the add fails, it returns false. They're checking to make sure that so far, all the values added to the row or column are valid there

Comment: @realmature you might want to post the implementation of `checkRow` and `checkColumn`. Also, an unrelated tip: try to keep your methods clean without too many nested statements. Sometimes neatness will cause the issue to jump out at you.

Comment: @souldzin @nbrooks I added the `checkRow` code.

Comment: What’s the point in passing i and 0 in the recursive call to fillBoard()? It sounds like starting over on the row?

Comment: @OleV.V. When I just passed the current location `j` it only solved the last column of each row

Comment: @OleV.V. I didn't want to start testing from the beginning of the puzzle every time

Comment: @realmature I do see a problem with your `checkRow()` method. You don't want to add a value to your set if it's value is `> 0` so you'll want to swap the order of the condition to `row[i]>0 && !set.add(row[i])`. That way it'll short circuit and won't add if `row[i]>0` is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that it didn't reset the space to 0 when the value was incorrect, so if it ever reached the max index and wasn't correct, it just left it. The below code works. Just waiting on another person in my group to deliver the box-checking method, but I will probably end up having to do that myself.

```
public boolean fillBoard(int[][] board, int row, int col){
    int index = 1;              //Next value to try when an empty is found
    boolean solved = false;

    for(int i = row; i < width; i++){       //For each row
        for(int j = col; j < height; j++){  //For each column
            if(board[i][j]==0){             //0 represents empty
                while(!solved){             //While the puzzle is unsolved
                    board[i][j] = index;    //Try to fill with index
                    if(checker.checkRow(board[i]) 
                            && checker.checkColumn(columnToArray(board, j))
                            //&& checker.checkBox(<input>)
                            ){
                            solved = fillBoard(board, i, 0); //Next space
                    }
                    if(!solved) board[i][j] = 0;
                    if(index < width){
                        index++;
                    }else{
                        return false;
                    }                        
                }
            }
        }
    }
    puzzle = copyPuzzle(board);
    return true;
}
```